# adding a new section on webpage using only css and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to click on an image on my webpage and it open a new section on the page that would be created in css and javascript/jquery.  I thought about using .addclass() but i am not entirely sure how to go about it.  Can anyone give me an example of this being done?

Comment: What do you mean a new section? Do you want to append a div on the body, do you want something like a lightbox? Where will this section be opened?

Comment: I am essentially trying to click on a button on my page that will reveal a new section of info. The section is not a hidden element in my html but created using css and js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example by clicking on a element with the id `foo` and adding a div with the id `bar` after that element:

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
    $(this).after('<div id="bar">Some content</div>');
});
```

Of course, there are multiple methods in jQuery which insert content somewhere in the DOM tree, see:

https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/

https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: this works how I want it too except if I click it more then once it will pop up multiple times.  Is there a way to make it come up only once after I click it? or if I click it a second time the information will go away?

Comment: You can check whether the element already exists, e.g. with "if ($("#bar").length)" you can check the existence of an element with the id "bar". Simply put that jQuery ".after" method or whatever you use into this if-condition.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.  As an example, you can simply attach a click event handler to your image, like so:

```
$('img').click(newSection);

function newSection() {
    $('#someDiv').append('<div class="newSection"></div>');
}
```